# Having a button in title bar of window

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup backgroundColor="white" id="mainTabGroup">
        <Tab id="byFav" title="fav" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
        <Window id="byFavWin' title='fav'>
                <TableView id="tableByFav" />

            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

index.js

```
var backButton = Ti.UI.createButton({left:0, width:80, height:25, backgroundColor:'red'});
$.byFavWin.setLeftNavButton(backButton);
```

I have tabgroup which has window which has the title 'Fav'.

Title occupay one line at the top of window, but

I would like to put the button next to the title in the title bar.

thanks to Mike S.

I have updated the code, but it doesn't work.

it shows no error but no button appears.

Could I have more hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the nav buttons in the Alloy markup, as well:

```
<Alloy>
  <TabGroup>
      <Tab>
          <Window title="Title" layout="vertical" backgroundColor="white">
              <LeftNavButton>
                  <Button>pop</Button>
              </LeftNavButton>
              <RightNavButton>
                  <Button>push</Button>
              </RightNavButton>
          </Window>
      </Tab>
  </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Window has a method called [setLeftNavButton()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-method-setLeftNavButton) and one for the right side as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tested and updated the articles.Do you have any idea?